# Filtrar Informação do PostgreSQL em tela Windows Forms usando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

Existe alguma forma de buscar as informações no postgresql por apelido? Mas sem utilizar *alias*, apenas no cadastro do campo na tabela eu já informar o nome real para o campo?

Exemplo:

> 1. id_cliente terá o nome de "Código Cliente"
> 2. dtNascimento como o nome de "Data de Nascimento"

Pois gostaria de criar uma classe genérica que funcione para qualquer tabela, colocando assim o nome do campo como filtro. 
Algo parecido como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Onde o campo para o filtro será o campo da tabela com o nome real.***

Que assim cada campo adicionado na tabela no futuro já poderá ser usado como filtro em uma tela de pesquisa e já com o nome real para o usuário.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso? só preciso de alguma dica do que pesquisar que o código vou me virando, mas não sei que tecnologia utilizar ou por onde começar.

Comment: Uma dúvida meio sem relação: está usando ASP.NET ou é uma aplicação desktop? Se for desktop, ela é WinForms ou WPF?

Comment: Desktop utilizando WPF mas pode ser aplicado com WinForms também, estou testando ainda.

Comment: Isso na verdade é indiferente. Basicamente o que você tem que fazer é o seguinte: Criar um atributo (`attribute`) personalizado para poder definir o nome (legível, de visualização) de cada propriedade e então ao montar a tela buscar estes nomes e preecher o `ComboBox`. O nome real da propriedade será o valor real do Combo e o nome definido pelo _attribute_ será o nome de visualização no `Combo` (`DisplayName`). Você consegue fazer isso tranquilamente com _reflection_.

Comment: @jbueno entendi, mas assim terei que implementar em cada tela de pesquisa os valores. Se eu utilizar conforme a resposta do Cigano, consigo somente alterando a entidade e subindo a migração para base, já mostrar na tela de pesquisa para o usuário

Comment: Das duas uma: ou eu não entendi o que você quer fazer ou você não entendeu a resposta do Cigano.

Comment: Assim @jbueno eu nao queria colocar na minha tela o valor de cada atributo, eu queria ja puxar da entidade o valor real do atributo Collumn. Pois assim não importa a tela que implemento, apenas passo uma lista das colunas e o usuário monta sua pesquisa, igual da imagem inicial da pergunta. 
O motivo disso, é conseguir criar uma classe genérica para fazer uma busca avançada em qualquer entidade.

Comment: É basicamente o que eu falei no comentário acima, @aprendiz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim. Use [`[Column]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[Column("Código Cliente")]
public int ClienteId { get; set; }

[Column("Data de Nascimento")]
public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
```

---

> O título da pergunta deveria ser "como filtrar no Winforms pelo nome da coluna exibido". Fiz uma simulação e logo devo editar esta resposta e colocar o exemplo num capítulo do Coding Craft porque sem querer fiz um tutorial sobre como usar Entity Framework com Windows Forms e PostgreSQL.

Vamos às perguntas:

> Existe alguma forma de buscar as informações no postgresql por apelido? mas sem utilizar alias, apenas no cadastro do campo na tabela eu já informar o nome real para o campo?

Não. Você precisa passar o nome da coluna mesmo. O que você pode fazer é a interface do usuário exibir o nome da coluna amigável e o código receber o nome da coluna como ele é de fato.

> Pois gostaria de criar uma classe genérica que funcione para qualquer tabela, colocando assim o nome do campo como filtro.

Isso envolve usar bastante [*Reflection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx). Usar o "nome do campo" não acho uma boa ideia, mas você pode exibir o nome do campo e pegar outro valor.

Para ilustrar, vou fazer um exemplo completo.

## *Model* e Tela

Modelei uma classe `Cliente` como exemplo assim:

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Identificador do Cliente")]
    public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Nome do Cliente")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Nome Fantasia")]
    public String Fantasia { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, cada propriedade da classe de `Cliente` tem um atributo [`[DisplayName]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Esse atributo será o que eu vou exibir para o usuário.

Feito isso, posso fazer o seguinte código para popular a compo "Campos de Pesquisa":

```
        var camposPesquisa = typeof(Cliente).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                           .Select(p => new {
                               Valor = p.Name,
                               Texto = p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName
                           }).ToList();

        comboBoxCampoPesquisa.ValueMember = "Valor";
        comboBoxCampoPesquisa.DisplayMember = "Texto";
        comboBoxCampoPesquisa.DataSource = camposPesquisa;
```

Ou seja, minha tela irá exibir os valores de `[DisplayName]`, mas os valores que irão para o código são os nomes dos meus campos:

[image: Exemplo de Combo de Campo para Pesquisa]

Posso fazer a mesma coisa para a condição, definindo um `Enum` `Condicao` e colocar atributos [`[Display]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) neles:

```
public enum Condicao
{
    [Display(Name = "Igual")]
    Igual,
    [Display(Name = "Diferente")]
    Diferente,
    [Display(Name = "Maior")]
    Maior,
    [Display(Name = "Menor")]
    Menor,
    [Display(Name = "Maior ou Igual")]
    MaiorOuIgual,
    [Display(Name = "Menor ou Igual")]
    MenorOuIgual
}
```

Para extrair o atributo dos `Enums`, você precisará de um método de extensão:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumValue)
            where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                        .First()
                        .GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
    }
}
```

Para usá-lo assim:

```
        var condicoes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Condicao))
            .Cast<Condicao>()
            .Select(c => new
            {
                Valor = c.ToString(),
                Texto = c.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name
            })
            .ToList();

        comboBoxCondicao.ValueMember = "Valor";
        comboBoxCondicao.DisplayMember = "Texto";
        comboBoxCondicao.DataSource = condicoes;
```

E então:

[image: Exemplo de Combo para Condição]

## *Grid*

Estou supondo que a inicialização da *Grid* é feita no evento `OnLoad` do seu *Form*

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        context.Clientes.Load();

        clienteBindingSource.DataSource =
            context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

        ...
    }
```

Apenas com isso tenho a pesquisa dos dados e a devida observação por eles através do contexto do Entity Framework. Feito isso, preciso colocar uma `CheckBox` e um evento para que ela dispare a filtragem no momento apropriado:

```
    private void checkBoxFiltrar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Filtrar(checkBoxFiltrar.Checked);
    }
```

Apenas como teste, fiz a filtragem por nome da seguinte forma:

```
    protected void Filtrar(bool checkFiltrar)
    {
        if (checkFiltrar)
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Where(c => c.Nome == textBoxValor.Text).ToList();
        else
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
```

Aqui é o ponto de partida para uma lógica mais robusta. Há duas formas de fazer: usando a biblioteca [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) ou montando [`Expressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx). Para esta resposta vou usar a primeira (que, no fundo, faz a mesma coisa que a segunda).

## Predicados Dinâmicos

Vamos montar apenas o predicado dinâmico para `Condicao.Igual`:

```
    protected void Filtrar(bool checkFiltrar)
    {
        if (checkFiltrar)
            // clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Where(c => c.Nome == textBoxValor.Text).ToList();
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes
                .Where(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString() + " == @0", textBoxValor.Text)
                .ToList();
        else
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
```

Verificando se funciona:

[image: Filtrando]

Por fim, como quero pesquisar não pelo texto exato, mas por uma parte dele, posso fazer o seguinte:

```
    protected void Filtrar(bool checkFiltrar)
    {
        if (checkFiltrar)
            // clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Where(c => c.Nome == textBoxValor.Text).ToList();
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes
                // .Where(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString() + " == @0", textBoxValor.Text)
                .Where(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString() + ".Contains(@0)", textBoxValor.Text)
                .ToList();
        else
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
```

Converter o `Enum` para um operador `String` fica como lição de casa.

Comment: Certo Obrigado, mas como poderia fazer a busca ou o retorno do SQL via  entity do collumn? fiquei com dúvida nessa parte

Comment: Ah, você quer criar várias entidades com código do cliente e data de nascimento? Que entidades seriam?

Comment: Exemplo:  
Entidade usuário, tenho os campos ( id_usuario, login, dtCriacao, situacao). Quero então jogar esses campos para combobox mas já usando o Collum passando o nome real dele.

Comment: Ah, @CiganoMorrisonMendez Ele quer colocar numa combo o tal do apelido (como valor para visualização) e também e nome real da propriedade (como valor real). Para que seja possível fazer um filtro usando o valor selecionado no `ComboBox`

Comment: Ah, então a pergunta é sobre fazer uma pesquisa em banco usando o `HeaderText` da coluna. Mas qual a utilidade disso? Não é melhor usar `Name`?

Comment: @jbueno exatamente isso que quero fazer.

Comment: @Aprendiz Como você está montando sua pesquisa hoje?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu sou iniciante, mas estou tentando criar de uma forma que não sei bem certo como começar, mas seria mais ou menos isso:  `// T sera minha entidadade .. usuario ou cliente 
    public abstract class BuscaAvancada<T>  where T : class
    {
        // retornar uma lista das colunas com os apelidos. essa parte nao sei como implementar
        public List<T> buscaColunas() {

            return listadeColunas();
        }
    }
`
O retorno dessa listaColunas colocaria no meu combobox para lista os campos (por apelido) na tela de pesquisa,

Comment: Assim o usuário monta sua pesquisa conforme qual campo deseja colocar, mas preciso que o campo seja o apelido. Não sei se ficou claro

Comment: Ah, entendi o que você quer. Eu vou precisar fazer umas simulações aqui. Pode demorar um pouco, ok?

Comment: @Aprendiz Aí está. Espero que esclareça sua dúvida.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez me passe seu endereço que vou te mandar uma caixa de cerveja haha .Era bem isso que eu precisava muito obrigado cara. Vou tentar implementar do meu jeito agora colocando tudo em uma classe e chamando onde eu preciso. Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Moro nos Estados Unidos, mas [tem esse link pra me mandar uma caixa de bera](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=58B8G88A995VJ). Um abraço!

Comment: Estou tentando validar quais campos não possui display name, mas como não existem recebo null exception. Mas mesmo verificando  os campos diferentes null ainda retorna o erro. `Where(p=> p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName != null).Select [ ... ]`. Quando chega no displayname recebo o erro.

Comment: Faça outra pergunta, por favor.