# Mapear Enum com condições de busca

Tags: c#, linq, enums

Tenho uma classe que faz as condições de busca da seguinte forma:

```
public enum EnumCondicao
{
    [Display(Name = "Igual")]
    Igual,
    [Display(Name = "Diferente")]
    Diferente,
    [Display(Name = "Maior")]
    Maior,
    [Display(Name = "Menor")]
    Menor,
    [Display(Name = "Maior ou Igual")]
    MaiorOuIgual,
    [Display(Name = "Menor ou Igual")]
    MenorOuIgual
}
```

Gostaria de mapear os atributos de um `enum` para um consulta dentro de uma condição no `LINQ`.

Sendo que,  cada variável terá seu valor real como condição no `LINQ` (`Igual = "Equals", Maior = ">", MaiorOuIgual = ">="`). Assim na utilização do `WHERE` com *Entity* gostaria de colocar o valor verdadeiro da varivel na busca.

Mas como poderia fazer isso? ou seria melhor utilizar apenas um `Switch case` com cada operação?

OBS:[Essa pergunta faz parte da resposta do Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198814/filtrar-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-postgresql-em-tela-windows-forms-usando-entity-framework)

Comment: [Vamos retomar o que falamos aqui, certo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198814/filtrar-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-postgresql-em-tela-windows-forms-usando-entity-framework)

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez desculpa cara foi erro meu, pensei que não podia referencia na pergunta outro link . Editei e coloquei a pergunta referenciada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Esta pergunta é continuação [desta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198814/filtrar-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-postgresql-em-tela-windows-forms-usando-entity-framework), que a resposta ficou um pouco densa mesmo. A ideia é agora esmiuçar melhor a técnica de filtragem que expliquei anteriormente.

Na resposta anterior, montei um exemplo em Windows Forms com uma tela contendo três campos: propriedade da entidade a ser filtrada, operador e condição.

[image: Tela do Windows Forms]

No clique do *checkbox* **Filtrar**, ativaríamos uma função também chamada `Filtrar`:

```
private void checkBoxFiltrar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Filtrar(checkBoxFiltrar.Checked);
}
```

A função está abaixo:

```
protected void Filtrar(bool checkFiltrar)
{
    if (checkFiltrar)
        clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes
            .Where(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString() + ".Contains(@0)", textBoxValor.Text)
            .ToList();
    else
        clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

    dataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

Agora devemos incluir a lógica para inserir o operador correto no nosso código com LINQ dinâmico. Antes, como só temos colunas `string`, coloquei um operador a mais, chamado "Contém":

```
namespace TesteWindowsForms.Models.Enums
{
    public enum Condicao
    {
        [Display(Name = "Contém")]
        Contem,
        [Display(Name = "Igual")]
        Igual,
        [Display(Name = "Diferente")]
        Diferente,
        [Display(Name = "Maior")]
        Maior,
        [Display(Name = "Menor")]
        Menor,
        [Display(Name = "Maior ou Igual")]
        MaiorOuIgual,
        [Display(Name = "Menor ou Igual")]
        MenorOuIgual
    }
}
```

A forma mais interessante que encontrei de implementar uma resolução de operador por `Enum` é usando *Extensions*, como a abaixo:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumValue)
            where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                        .First()
                        .GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
    }

    public static String CondicaoParaLinq(this Condicao condicao)
    {
        switch (condicao)
        {
            case Condicao.Contem:
                return ".Contains(@0)";
            case Condicao.Diferente:
                return " != @0";
            case Condicao.Maior:
                return " > @0";
            case Condicao.MaiorOuIgual:
                return " >= @0";
            case Condicao.Menor:
                return " < @0";
            case Condicao.MenorOuIgual:
                return " <= @0";
            case Condicao.Igual:
            default:
                return " == @0";
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
    protected void Filtrar(bool checkFiltrar)
    {
        if (checkFiltrar)
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes
                .Where(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString() + 
                       ((Condicao)Enum.Parse(typeof(Condicao), comboBoxCondicao.SelectedValue.ToString())).CondicaoParaLinq(), 
                       textBoxValor.Text)
                .ToList();
        else
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Ou seja, posso filtrar agora por "contém" ou "igual", vindo da tela:

[image: Filtrado por "contém"]

Mas não faz muito sentido usar maior, menor ou menor ou igual, por exemplo, em campos `string`, certo? Significa que, toda vez que seu campo para pesquisa mudar, você precisará restringir os operadores.

Para isso, criei este *Helper*:

```
public static class CondicoesHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Condicao>> condicoesPorTipo = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Condicao>> {
        { typeof(String), new List<Condicao> { Condicao.Igual, Condicao.Diferente, Condicao.Contem } },
        { typeof(int), new List<Condicao> { Condicao.Igual, Condicao.Diferente, Condicao.Maior, Condicao.MaiorOuIgual, Condicao.Menor, Condicao.MenorOuIgual } },
        { typeof(long), new List<Condicao> { Condicao.Igual, Condicao.Diferente, Condicao.Maior, Condicao.MaiorOuIgual, Condicao.Menor, Condicao.MenorOuIgual } },
        { typeof(Guid), new List<Condicao> { Condicao.Igual, Condicao.Diferente } }
    };

    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> FiltrarCondicoesPorTipoDeCampo(Type tipoDoCampo)
    {
        return condicoesPorTipo[tipoDoCampo]
               .Select(c => new
               {
                   Valor = c.ToString(),
                   Texto = c.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name
               })
               .AsEnumerable();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> TodasAsCondicoes()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Condicao))
            .Cast<Condicao>()
            .Select(c => new
            {
                Valor = c.ToString(),
                Texto = c.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name
            })
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Agora vou precisar amarrar um evento ao campo de pesquisa. Quando ele muda, a lista de condições deve ser atualizada. Ou seja:

```
    private void comboBoxCampoPesquisa_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<dynamic> condicoes;
        if (comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            condicoes = CondicoesHelper.FiltrarCondicoesPorTipoDeCampo(typeof(Cliente).GetProperty(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString()).PropertyType);
        } else
        {
            condicoes = CondicoesHelper.TodasAsCondicoes();
        }

        comboBoxCondicao.ValueMember = "Valor";
        comboBoxCondicao.DisplayMember = "Texto";
        comboBoxCondicao.DataSource = condicoes.ToList();
    }
```

Feito isso, posso comentar o preenchimento das condições no `OnLoad`:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        context.Clientes.Load();

        clienteBindingSource.DataSource =
            context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

        var camposPesquisa =
            typeof(Cliente).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    Valor = p.Name,
                    Texto = p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName
                }).ToList();

        comboBoxCampoPesquisa.ValueMember = "Valor";
        comboBoxCampoPesquisa.DisplayMember = "Texto";
        comboBoxCampoPesquisa.DataSource = camposPesquisa;

        //var condicoes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Condicao))
        //    .Cast<Condicao>()
        //    .Select(c => new
        //    {
        //        Valor = c.ToString(),
        //        Texto = c.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name
        //    })
        //    .ToList();

        //comboBoxCondicao.ValueMember = "Valor";
        //comboBoxCondicao.DisplayMember = "Texto";
        //comboBoxCondicao.DataSource = condicoes;

        viewModel = new FiltrosPesquisaViewModel
        {

        };
    }
```

E o método `Filtrar`? Fica assim:

```
    protected void Filtrar(bool checkFiltrar)
    {
        if (checkFiltrar)
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes
                .Where(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString() +
                       ((Condicao)Enum.Parse(typeof(Condicao), comboBoxCondicao.SelectedValue.ToString())).CondicaoParaLinq(),
                       Convert.ChangeType(textBoxValor.Text, typeof(Cliente).GetProperty(comboBoxCampoPesquisa.SelectedValue.ToString()).PropertyType))
                .ToList();
        else
            clienteBindingSource.DataSource = context.Clientes.Local.ToBindingList();

        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Para testar, coloquei uma coluna a mais na tela, "Número de Usuários", que é inteira:

[image: Operador "Diferente"]

[image: Operador "Maior"]

Por fim, os operadores são filtrados de acordo com o tipo do campo:

[image: Operadores Filtrados 1]

[image: Operadores Filtrados 2]

Comment: Show você me respondeu a pergunta la no ´Switch Case´, que era a minha principal duvida, pois pensei que deveria mapear de alguma forma a  numeração ao invés de utilizar ´Switch Case´

Comment: Desculpe o tamanho, mas sem o resto da resposta você teria vários erros estranhos (porque eu os tive aqui), então elaborei algo um pouco maior.

Comment: Cigado, poderia só detalhar o que esse método `TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumValue)` faz? pois fique com muita duvida nessa parte, não entendi porque utilizar. Muito obrigado pelo auxilio até o momento

Comment: Ela é usada neste trecho: `.Select(c => new
               {
                   Valor = c.ToString(),
                   Texto = c.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name
               })`. Só para simplificar e não ficar uma declaração gigantesca na hora de definir `Texto`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma resposta mais curta. Supondo que você tenha um método que recebe uma lista, um número a comparar e uma instância da sua enumeração:

```
public List<int> Metodo(List<int> input, int comparado, EnumCondicao condicao)
{
    List<int> resultado = input.Where(i =>
        (condicao == EnumCondicao.Igual && i == comparado)
        || (condicao == EnumCondicao.Diferente && i != comparado)
        || (condicao == EnumCondicao.Maior && i > comparado)
        || (condicao == EnumCondicao.Menor && i < comparado)
        || (condicao == EnumCondicao.MaiorOuIgual && i >= comparado)
        || (condicao == EnumCondicao.MenorOuIgual && i <= comparado)
    ).ToList();

    return resultado;
}
```

CQD

Comment: +1, mas não é melhor fazer genérico? Esse caso só atende inteiros.

Comment: Não é possível fazer completamente genérico pois os operadores `>`, `<`, `>=` e `<=` não podem ser implementados pra interface (i.e.: não é possível trocar `int` por `IComparable` ou similar no meu exemplo). Mas esse código já é um exemplo aplicável pra maioria das estruturas do .NET.